# When I add new datanode to the cluster, what happens to new blocks

Tags: hadoop, datanode

When i add new data node to the running cluster, there are some running jobs, what will happen to the new blocks which are created by running jobs?

Comment: Please update your post title to be more descriptive

Answer (score 0, accepted):

New blocks will be sent to new datanodes, as determined by the NameNode.

You don't need to stop existing running jobs.